# Correct HEX code for Android Recommended Palette

Tags: android

In the Dev guide's Icon Design Guidelines, there is a recommended color palette given for the Launcher icon. If you look at the HEX color codes in the bottom row, the green and the orange are given the same code (#FF6600). This is the correct code for the orange, so what is the correct code for the green?

Comment: Very good spot. Maybe someone should mention this to someone at Google to get it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good spot! It should be `#669933`